# Having trouble creating a stored procedure using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new to MQSQL, I have been working with MSSQL so the syntax for me is challenging. I'm getting this error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; ... right syntax to use near 'declare @side LONGTEXT;
>    declare @post BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;
>    @side = '7082';
>    ' at line 3 **

but the window also has a big red X next to the select statement.
I have double checked the data types of the variables Meta_Value is a LONGTEXT and post_id is BIGINT(20)

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS DailyDishData()

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE DailyDishData()

declare @side LONGTEXT;
declare @post BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;

@side = '7082';

BEGIN
select @post = post_id from `wp_dfh0payzs9_postmeta` where meta_key = 'ftrecipe_id' and meta_value = @side;
END 

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot/misplaced the `BEGIN` and `END` keywords around your procedure

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS DailyDishData //

CREATE PROCEDURE DailyDishData()
BEGIN
    declare @side LONGTEXT;
    declare @post BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;

    set @side = '7082';

    select @post = post_id
    from `wp_dfh0payzs9_postmeta` 
    where meta_key = 'ftrecipe_id' and meta_value = @side;
END 
//

DELIMITER ;
```

ignoring the fact that a hard coded number does not make much sense in a procedure and that you do not seems to use the `@post` variable

Comment: Could you explain what the problem was and how you fixed it?